# Magento EE shopping cart rule?

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, cart-rule, shopping

I am using "Magento EE". I have a problem here: "If someone buys two products, they should get 10% of the total amount added to his account for use on the next order"

Condition is here:- Buy any two products & you get 10% amount credit in your account. Please tell me the condition I should setup in the shopping cart rule.

Is there a [free] third part module to credit amount in customer account?

Comment: What version of EE is this for? It sounds like you want to reward loyalty points not a discount based on the cart contents.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not included in any release of Magento EE.

However, as Joe Constant mentioned in the comments, you could use the reward points module (that is built in) and get it close to what you need.

I would also checkout Sweetooth as a 3rd party module.